# Volatility Surface Constituents, do's and dont's

Tags: options, volatility, implied-volatility, volatility-smile, best-practices

Recently I have been working a lot with implied volatility and volatility surfaces.

The basic idea is easy to follow:
1) Gather market prices of options at different (Strike,Expiry)
2) Calculate implied volatilities
3) Interpolate/Extrapolate as needed to emulate a continuum of option market prices.

This question concerns point 1), namely the selection of prices and what options to use.

Let's say I use European option prices:

*Would it be OK to mix put/call prices such that I only ever calculate implied volatility for in-the-money options?*

*If so, I assume this surface can then immediately be used to calculate a fair value for an in-the-money call option (even though the implied volatility is calculated from the put option at the same (Strike,Expiry)?*

*Does it make sense to price American options using this volatility surface constructed from European options?*

Let's say I use American option prices:

*Does this give additional value as opposed to using a surface constructed from European option prices?*

*Is it again possible to mix put/call prices into the same surface? Or does that not make sense?*

*Is it at all possible to mix american option prices with european option prices?*

As you may guess, I have had a hard time finding articles or papers that discuss how volatility surfaces should be used in actual practice. Do I need one surface for puts, one for calls, and one each for european and americans? Or do I just need a single surface consisting of a mix of european put and calls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would it be OK to mix put/call prices such that I only ever calculate implied volatility for in-the-money options?

No. Use OTM options because they usually have narrower bid-ask spread. Ideally you calculate all IVs, and then use highest bid IV, smallest ask IV.

> If so, I assume this surface can then immediately be used to calculate ...
>   Yes, then you can calculate all puts and calls.
>
> Does it make sense to price American options ...
>   Yes.

Now, the last 3 questions - yes, you can mix European-style, and American-style IVs, or use one IV surface to price the other. But I doubt its usefulness from practical point - AFAIK the only options that trade both styles are SPX (European on CBOE and American/futures on CME) and liquidity on both is among the highest in the world. You are unlikely to see any tradable mispricings in one product vs another.